# Laravel and MySQL get data by week

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have this function that gets the data from MySQL by month using carbon

```
$calls = \DB::table('calls') 
        ->where('owned_by_id', $report->id) 
        ->where(\DB::raw('month(created_at)'), Carbon::today()->month)
        ->get();
        $report->callsCount = $calls->count();
```

It works fine what i want to do is to get the data per week

I tried modifying the code like this:

```
   ->where(\DB::raw('week(created_at)'), Carbon::today()->week)
```

but i get an error in Laravel

> Unknown getter 'week'

Comment: you want to get data from which week , means from today to previous 7 days ??

Comment: `   ->where(\DB::raw('month(created_at)'), Carbon::today()->month)` This code is exactly same, so what have you modified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look you need to filter date by `week` which mean date range try this

```
$calls = \DB::table('calls') 
    ->where('owned_by_id', $report->id) 
    ->whereBetween('created_at', [Carbon::now()->subWeek()->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"), Carbon::now()])
    ->get();
$report->callsCount = $calls->count();
```

This mean to get all data from last 7 days to now based on carbon docs https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/ and laravel docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses

Comment: Thank you very much exactly what i wanted Thank you

Comment: Rabena yebareklak :D

Answer (score 0):

Use whereBetween with two carbon date instances.

```
->whereBetween('created_at', [
    Carbon\Carbon::parse('last monday')->startOfDay(),
    Carbon\Carbon::parse('next friday')->endOfDay(),
])
```

Comment: Thank you very much but it didn't work for me idk why

Comment: What results you got and what are you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

Like @Abrar says, if you need to count total calls of the current month u can use whereBetween:

```
$calls = \DB::table('calls') 
        ->where('owned_by_id', $report->id) 
        ->whereBetween('created_at', [
            now()->locale('en')->startOfWeek(),
            now()->locale('en')->endOfWeek(),
        ])
        ->get();
$report->callsCount = $calls->count();
```

But u want to count the total numerb of calls per each week u need to use groupBy.
Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but i got method locale doesn't exist

Comment: perhaps you have an older version of Laravel and don't have the now() helper